# Отправка письма при помощи PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. При нажатии на кнопку «Перезвоните мне» идёт редирект на пустую страницу site.ru/send.php

Как сделать, чтобы без перезагрузки страницы чуть ниже добавлялось «Сообщение отправилось»?

[image: http://f1.s.qip.ru/gbw3dGA8.png]

Содержимое send.php

```
<?php

if((isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они

        $to = 'test@test.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <test@test.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail

        echo '<script>alert("Сообщение отправлено")</script>';
}

?>
```

```html
<form action="send.php" method="post" class="form">
  <input placeholder="Номер телефона" required/>
  <button type="submit">Перезвоните мне</button>
</form>
```

Comment: вам нужно в send.php прописать условия что бы выводилось то или иное сообщение если письмо отправилось или не отправилось. Данные с формы обработчику send.php отправлять через ajax запрос, с помощью него и выводить сообщение под формой.

Comment: Звучит как заклинание!

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код что в send.php

Comment: Дмитрий. Что нужно добавить в конец send.php, чтобы при его срабатывании в DIV с названием «BLABLABLA» добавлялся текст «SUCCESS»?

Comment: добавил ответ, зададите только стиль  классу `message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас нет возможности протестировать но все должно работать. В send.php в конце внес небольшие правки, изменил немного код формы и добавил аякс запрос.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js'></script>



<form action="send.php" method="POST" name="form" class="form" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" required />
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Перезвоните мне">
</form>
<div class="masBlock"></div>

<script>
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".form").ajaxForm({
   type: "POST",
   success: function(e){
    alert(e);
    $(".masBlock").html(e);
   },

  });
 });
</script>

<!--

<?php

if((isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они

        $to = 'test@test.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <test@test.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        $mailSend = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
}


if($mailSend) { // если переменная существует то письмо отправилось
        echo '<div class="message">"Сообщение отправлено"</div>'; // ели письмо отпрaвилось то выводим сообщение
}
else {
    echo '<div class="message">"Сообщение не отправлено"</div>'; // ели письмо не отправилось то выводим сообщение
}

?>

-->
```

Comment: Дмитрий, а куда необходимо добавить этот код $(function() {
 $(".button").click(function...? В конец send.php?

Comment: можете вставить после формы, подкоректировал ответ.

Comment: После отправки идёт редирект на site/send.php, где на белом фоне написано "Сообщение отправлено".

Comment: изменил ответ, добавил плагин для отправки форм и внес некоторые правки.

Comment: Почему-то скрипт не срабатывает (как-будто его вообще нет), но всё равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: вы плагин для отправки форм `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js'></script>` подключили?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form class="form" id="send">
    <input name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" required autofocus/>
    <button type="submit">Перезвоните мне</button>
    <div class="successSend" style="display: none"></div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function () {

        "use strict";

        function _send() {
            var form = $('#send'),
                    mes = $('.successSend');

            form.on('submit', function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'send.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: $(this).serialize();
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res.type == 'success') {
                            mes.css('display', 'block').text(res.mess);
                        } else {
                            mes.css('display', 'block').text(res.mess)
                        }
                    }
                })
            });

        }

        return {
            sender: _send()
        }


    }())
```

**PHP**

```
if((isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] != "")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они

    $to = 'test@test.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
    $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
    $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
    $headers .= "From: Отправитель <test@test.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
    $res =  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
    if ($res) {
        return json_encode(['status'=> 'success', 'mess' => 'Сообщение отправлено']);
    } else {
        return json_encode(['status'=> 'error', 'mess' => 'Сообщение не удалось отправлено']);
    }

}
```

**Я думаю идея понятна**